# count of extracted text for each number

Tags: regex, awk, sed, grep

I have a text file with lot of SQL queries those look something like this...

```
select * from sometable where customernos like '%67890%';
select name, city from sometable where customernos like '%67890%';
select * from othertable where customernos like '%12345%';
```

I can get the count using a command like this...

```
grep -v 67890 file.txt | wc -l
```

But is there any way I can get the count of all customer numbers report like...

```
12345 1
67890 2
```

Comment: Did you try `grep -c '[0-9]{5}' file`? Or something like `grep -o '[0-9]{5}' file | wc -l`? `'\b[0-9]{5}\b'`?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 `grep -o '[0-9]{5}' file` will extract all matches, not lines. And I forgot to add `-E` above. Should be `grep -oE '\b[0-9]{5}\b'`

Comment: You can use `grep -oE '\b[0-9]{5}\b' file | sort | uniq -c` to print number of 5-digit number occurrences with the found values on the right. [Demo](https://ideone.com/Lj6FTU).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU grep,sort,uniq and awk):

```
grep -Eo '\b[0-9]{5}\b' file | sort -n | uniq -c | awk '{print $2,$1}'
```

Find 5 digit numbers, sort them, filter and count them and then reverse the columns.

Just for fun, here is a sed solution:

```
sed -nE 'H;$!d;x;s/[^0-9]/ /g;s/ +/ /g;
        :a;x;s/.*/1/;x;tb;
        :b;s/^(( \S+\b).*)\2\b/\1/;Tc;x;s/.*/expr & + 1/e;x;tb;
        :c;G;s/^ (\S+)(.*)\n(.*)/\1 \3\n\2/;/^[0-9]{5} /P;s/.*\n//;/\S/ba' file
```

Slurp the file into memory.

Space separate numbers.

Reduce multiple occurrences of the first number to one and count the occurrences.

Print the first number and its occurrences if it fits the criteria.

Repeat with all other numbers.

Comment: I have accepted this answer because grep command is more readable than awk and easy to remember.

Answer (score 4):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
match($0,/%[^%][0-9]{5}/){
  val[substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1)]++
}
END{
  for(i in val){
    print i,val[i]
  }
}' Input_file
```

For shown samples output will be as follows.

```
12345 1
67890 2
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above.

```
awk '                                      ##Starting awk program from here.
match($0,/%[^%][0-9]{5}/){                 ##Using match function to match from % to till 5 digits before next occurrence of % here.
  val[substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1)]++     ##Creating val with index of sub-string of matched regex above.
}
END{                                       ##Starting END block of this program from here.
  for(i in val){                           ##Traversing through val here.
    print i,val[i]                         ##Printing value of i and value of array val with index i here.
  }
}' Input_file                              ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: Thanks. This is correct. but I will like to select only 5 digit numbers. This is returning 10 or 12 digits as well. Is that possible?

Comment: @shantanuo, sure changed the regex now to catch 5 digits kindly check it now once and let know in case of queries.